# Varchar and char with same size which is bigger?

Tags: mysql

Excuse me,
If I have a String the length is 10.
Then, I save it on db the type is varchar and the length is 10 too.
Then, I save it too on char type, the length is 10..
Which is bigger it's size?
Varchar(10) or char(10)

And where can I get this documentation? about data type and size at mysql?

Thank you

Comment: [First search result for `mysql column sizes`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html). Seriously, did you even try?

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, `CHAR` data types require `M x w` bytes of storage where M is the size of the field and w is the size (in bytes) of the max-length character in the character set.

`VARCHAR` types require `L + 1`(or `L + 2` for more than 255 bytes) bytes where L is the length of the string in bytes.

In the case where all data in the field is the same length, a `CHAR` data type will take up less space, but where the length of the data will vary, `VARCHAR` is a better choice.

For example:  Suppose 2 rows of data in a field - XXXXXXXXXX, XXX

If the data type is `CHAR(10)` the total size would be 10 x 1 x 2 or 20 bytes.
If the data type is `VARCHAR(10)` the total size would be (10 + 1) + (3 + 1) or 15 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Varchar takes more storage space because it stores a length prefix in MySQL. Char does not because it isn't needed. (i.e. it is a fixed length string so the database knows how long the actual string is.) Char is padded with spaces at the end when the actual string is shorter than the column length.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html for all the details about this.

Comment: it depends. the length prefix is of a definite size and allow for the var_char to use less space when it is not filled to capacity. a char(30) containing `abc` will be bigger then a var_char(30) containing `abc`

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier, yes you're right if you are not filling the column to its maximum capacity and/or using variable length strings. My comparison was meant my using fixed-length values in either a char or varchar column.